# I have a mid-2012 MacBook Air, and the Service Battery alert is showing

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, applecare

My 13" Macbook Air recently started showing the "service battery" alert. It's the mid-2012 model, and is still under Apple Care. The alert seems to appear mainly when I'm running off the battery. Is this a battery issue or a bug in the system?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Battery warning ''Service battery"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2638/battery-warning-service-battery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is still under Applecare I would absolutely get it checked out.  In the very least if there is an issue, you will get the battery replaced under warranty and be able to enjoy a few more years with it.

Answer (score 1):

This the battery failing, get it checked out and replaced for free.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what version of OS X you're running, but if it's 10.9, note that other users have reported a change in battery alerts after upgrading to that version.  http://www.zdnet.com/macbook-users-seeing-service-battery-message-after-mavericks-upgrade-7000022588/

Open Utilities > System Information, click on "Power" in the left column and see what stats show up for your battery. This will be useful when talking to Applecare.

Comment: I'm running Mavericks

Comment: So check that first link I posted.