# MacBook Air's battery doesn't charge, Service Battery state, but only 400 cycles

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, charging

Yesterday everything was fine with the battery in my MacBook Air 13'' 2012 (2 years old). It was lasting for 4-5 hours like new. Today, all of a sudden, the battery has stopped charging at all (I have only 40% left). While the power cable is plugged in, its LED doesn't indicate any colour. I rebooted the system, no difference. In System Info I have:

Cycle Count: 409
Condition: Service Battery

I heard that the lifetime of the battery should be 1000 cycles. I didn't update any software recently.

Does it all mean that the battery is dead? Or maybe there is a way to conquer it? Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Battery warning ''Service battery"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2638/battery-warning-service-battery)

Answer (score 2):

It happens to me on my MBA, no charging light on.

By moving the mag connector (like let it snap in few times) it then comes up.

Just a bad connection. You can try cleaning it with alcohol.

And I also have the "Service battery" but that is only a recommendation.

Next level would be displaying "Replace soon, or Replace Now.

While the light on the connector is not on, I can see in the battery indicator it is still charging, telling me the wall plug adapter/converter is still working.

To check the health status of your battery, look in the about this Mac - Power,

Charge Information:

Charge Remaining (mAh):   2712

Fully Charged:    No

Charging: No

Full Charge Capacity (mAh):   5014

Health Information:

Cycle Count:  528

The Full Charge Capacity will tell you the health status  >5000 or higher is good.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but the battery condition in the system says "Service Battery", instead of "Normal". Even with unplugged connector, that's the main problem. Also, it doesn't charge at all anyway.

Comment: Just seen your edit. Will do a cleaning then, but still the battery condition status is quite alarming. Full Charge Capacity is 5069.

Comment: That is a good battery considering been 2 Yrs old. Just like what I have.

Comment: Trick with moving/touching the mag connector doesn't work/change anything. When I plug it in, the battery indicator is NOT charging (the icon stays the same without the lightening bit), and you say for you it does charge (but without LED showing any colour)? Cleaned with alcohol, no difference :(

Comment: In that case there are 2 possibilities. One is to try the SMC reset. The second one is your charger is dead.

Comment: SMC reset on MBA http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295

Comment: Thank you for your help. I reset SMC, didn't help... I'll try to plug in another magsafe and will see!

Comment: This is the best answer to a question that has been duplicated several times.  Should be merged with https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2638/battery-warning-service-battery